# How do you say not equal to in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, syntax, equals

This is a much simpler example of what I'm trying to do in my program but is a similar idea. In an, if statement how do I say not equal to?

Is `!=` correct?

```
def test
  vara = 1
  varb = 2
  if vara == 1 && varb != 3
    puts "correct"
  else
    puts "false"
  end
end
```

Comment: @GerCrowley use the `irb` console utility to test quick snippets

Comment: Ruby has at least three operators to compare equality check http://www.wellho.net/mouth/985_Equality-in-Ruby-eql-and-equal-.html for more info

Answer (score 133, accepted):

Yes. In Ruby the not equal to operator is:

`!=`

You can get a full list of ruby operators here: 
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_operators.htm.